# How to create a custom NSSharingService

Tags: macos, osx-lion

With the new Sharing Service of Mountain Lion, I can use `NSSharingService` to create a custom service and use existing system services like Twitter.

How can i add my own service to the system services list so other apps can use it?

Answer (score 3):

In short, you cannot create a custom `NSSharingService` available for other apps system-wide. The only way to integrate your service into another app, is to make a library or framework available for other developers. In this case, they should explicitly add it to their projects.